# Django blank FileField how to serialize without getting error

Tags: django, django-models, django-serializer

I have a file field that is defined in my model like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    profile_picture = models.FileField(blank=True)
```

Then, I have a JSON view like this:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

class ProfileView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format='json'):
        profile = ...
        profile_serialized = model_to_dict(profile)
        return Response(profile_serialized, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I am using DRF but DRF is not my concern. `model_to_dict` converts the model to dictionary, so I can output it as JSON. However, I keep getting validation error:

> ValueError: The 'profile_picture' attribute has no file associated with it.

If the field field is empty, I can't serialize it. How should I do approach solving this? Should I create a `@property` function in the models that does the checking or is there a better approach to this?

Thanks!

Comment: related: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27492

Comment: What is the correct way to serialize a model then? I am not able to find anything regarding that.

Comment: I ended up using DRF Serializer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using DRF Serializers instead of `model_to_dict` and everything worked fine.